# Split date range into day wise rows in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which have 3 columns

[image]

An I want to split on each day based on Promo_Period_Start and Promo_Period_End

What I tried is the following

```
declare @d datetime;
set @d = getdate();

select *
from   [dbo].[T]
where  @d between Promo_Period_Start and Promo_Period_End
```

SAMPLE DATA

[image]

Comment: And what is wrong with what you tried?

Comment: Sample data and expected results will probably help here.

Comment: But what results are you expecting here? You reference `Promo_Period_Start ` and `Promo_Period_End` but neither of those columns exist if your sample. Your SQL and sample have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive CTE

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, Promo_Period_Start,Promo_Period_End
    FROM T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, DATEADD(day, 1, Promo_Period_Start), Promo_Period_End
    FROM cte
    WHERE Promo_Period_Start < Promo_Period_End
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```